# passing member function pointer to a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass a Class member function pointer

```
template < typename CLASS, typename TYPE1, typename TYPE2 > 
  void WriteFunctionHelper(CLASS* pOwner, PropInfoType::iterator& it, WriterPtr pw, WriterPtr (Writer::*func)(TYPE1, TYPE2) ) {
     MemberProperty<CLASS,TYPE2> *ptr = (MemberProperty<CLASS, TYPE2> *)it->second;
     const char *propertName = ptr->m_propertyName.c_str(); 
      if ( !ptr->m_getterFn ) { 
        throw; 
      } 
      pw->*func(propertName,(pOwner->*(ptr->m_getterFn))()); 
  }
```

I am getting compiler error `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments` what is wrong that I am doing

Comment: If your library is new enough, consider using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Can I use std::function and std::bind for version less than C++11

Comment: Boost have these for non-C++11 systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add bracers around `pw->*func`

```
(pw->*func)(propertName,(pOwner->*(ptr->m_getterFn))());
```

Comment: It's another problem which type, check that this is a pointer or use . to access to function member

Answer (score 1):

Your `func` pointer can be used to trigger a function expecting 2 parameters - first of `TYPE1` and second of `TYPE2`. You're trying to send `propertName` to it, which is of type `const char *`. Second parameter also of different type as it's actually a type returned from `(pOwner->*(ptr->m_getterFn))()` and not `TYPE2`.

Edit: plus see answer from @DenisErmolin